# Как реализовать тонкого клиента для wpf приложения наподобие тонкого клиента "1С Предприятие"?

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net, сервер, wcf

Есть: сервер, wpf приложение и единственное требование к тонкому клиенту: если есть возможность, сделать его кроссплатформенной.

Стоит задача: сделать wpf приложение серверным(чтобы тонкий клиент мог взаимодействовать с wpf приложением на сервере), реализовать тонкий клиент наподобие тонкого клиента приложения "1С Предприятие".

Так как ранее не имел опыта в области ни web, ни клиент-серверных приложений я не знаю с чего начать.
В основном интересуют ответы на вопросы "Как правильно реализовать тонкого клиента? и Как сделать wpf приложение серверным", внутри которых есть некоторые детали, которые важны для понимания деталей:

1. "Какие технологии применить(wcf, asp.net...)?"
2. "Как будет происходить взаимодействие тонкого клиента с wpf приложения на сервере?"

   Рис. Тонкий клиент  "1C Предприятие"[image: 1]

Comment: Во первых, WPF не кроссплатформенный, вы можете написать всю логику на .Net Core и под нее уже писать UI под разные системы. Во вторых, а при чем тут сервер и WPF? WPF, это интерфейс (UI), а сервера на сколько я знаю работают на службах, демонах и прочей "нечисти", которая висит фоном и что-то обрабатывает, так что мне ваша формулировка `wpf приложение серверным` не понятна. По поводу вопросов: 1. Какие хотите, все зависит от задачи. Можете поднять REST API, можете сделать например RPC, а можете вообще использовать сокеты. 2. Зависит от первого, обычно это запрос к API и обработка результата.

Comment: `Как сделать wpf приложение серверным` - ответ никак. Так же как нельзя сделать Word серверным приложением. WPF приложение - рабочее место для одного человека. WPF прил. может быть клиентом в клиент-серверной конфигурации. Когда клиент, только принимает данные от юзера и отображает их, а вся логика обработки данных осуществляется на стороне сервера, тогда такой клиент называется тонким. В качестве сервера вам надо будет использовать ASP.Net Core реализующее Web API, в качестве СУБД SQL Server, в качестве клиента WPF или Xamarin, или Blazor webassambly (в мае-июне должна выйти первая версия).

Comment: Для начала определитесь, какие функции нужны от приложения. Если простой ввод-вывод текстовой информации, то чем плох web-app, через API или же напрямую через браузер? ... И да, WPF (**Windows** Presentation Foundation) не может быть кроссплатформенным по определению.

Comment: Самый тонкий из всех тонких клиентов - это браузер, к тому же кросплатформеннее браузера нет ничего. Сервер можно на C# написать (можно даже под Linux с фреймворком `.NET Core`), а клиент под браузер. Ну а WPF, как уже выше сказано - это только для Windows, первая буква в аббревиатуре как бы намекает. :) Сервер по стандарту REST API (например JSON для данных), клиент на каком-нибудь JavaScript фреймворке типа Webix (формы, таблички, кнопочки, графики). А 1С - далеко не идеал для подражания, во всяком случае, в вопросе технологий.